# How do I grep/awk this?

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I'm pretty new to Linux and I'm still learning the commands. All I want to do is format my .txt file.

Here is what my file looks like:

```
hello hello
goodbye goodbye
random random
example example
last last
```

All I want to do is remove the space and replace it with a semi-colon.

For example:

```
hello:hello
goodbye:goodbye
random:random
example:example
last:last
```

I'm not sure what command will accomplish this task, I'm pretty sure it's grep or awk. It would be great if someone can help me out on this. Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Formatting : Confusion using awk NR Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941997/file-formatting-confusion-using-awk-nr-variable)

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is the simplest tool for this task:

```
sed 's/ /:/' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

With `tr` (translate all spaces to colons)

```
tr ' ' ':'
```

With `sed` (replace all spaces with colons)

```
sed 's/ /:/g'
```

With `awk` (change output field separator then recompute/output `$0` for each line)

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=":"}{$1=$1;print}'
```

With Perl (standard `-pne` read-eval-print loop replacing characters):

```
perl -pne 's/ /:/g'
```

With a C filter program, since this *is* a programming Q&A site :-)

```
// Call with: progName <infile

#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ') ch = ':';
        putchar (ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are probably many other ways to do it as well but I'd probably opt for the `tr` utility since it's the simplest, with the clearest intent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the stream editor `sed` to replace space by colon as follows:
    sed -i 's/ /:/' filename
where `filename` is your file.